# Read Thai characters from IBM Emulator AS400 5250

Tags: ibm-midrange, thai, hllapi

I am trying to read thai characters from AS400 5250 IBM emulator using hllapi c# but code is unable to read thai characters. It can read english characters properly but thai characters are appearing blank in variable. Has anyone faced the similar issue? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The AS/400 doesn't use 3270, it uses 5250. It's similar to 3270 but not the same. The TN5250 interface is covered by RFC1205. I've requested an edit.

Comment: Thank you. Any pointers will be appreciated regarding reading of non-English characters from AS400 using hllapi.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at the CCSID setting on the IBMi system.  Hopefully it is set to something other than 65535.  If it is set to 65535, that would be a good place to start.

To view the default CCSID, use: `dspsysval qccsid`

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I tried searching for CCSID settings but didn't find it inside AS400. Is it something to be done AS400 administrator or we can also change it. Just note that we don't have admin rights on the system.